# How to configure OmniAuth with Grape?

Tags: ruby, facebook, api, ruby-grape

I am using the code below:

```
require 'grape'
require 'omniauth'
require 'omniauth-facebook'

class Auth < Grape::API
  include OmniAuth::Strategy

  format :json

  use Rack::Session::Cookie
  use OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook, 'xx', 'xxx'

end
```

What am I doing wrong? When I access `/auth/facebook` I get a missing route.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the omniauth stuff to your config.ru file:

```
require 'omniauth'
require 'omniauth-facebook'

use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: 'some long secret code here'

use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']
end

# run your base api here. Root, Base, whatever you called it.
run API::Root
```